# Running Flask locally. I want to display images based on names generated in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, flask

I am using d3 and Flask to display tree diagrams in my browser. The whole thing is stored and operated locally.

I want to display a relevant image when the user hovers over each node in the tree diagram.

For the JSON data that the tree diagram is based on, I am using url_for and my static folder, like this:

```
d3.json("{{ url_for('static', filename=json_data) }}", function(error, flare) {
    // Lots of code
```

The same thing for including the d3:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='d3.js') }}"></script>
```

However, when it comes to the images that I want to appear on hover, I am using data from the JSON to create the name of the image. Since this means using JavaScript variables rather than python ones, I can't see how to display it using url_for.

As an alternative, I have tried using a range of different absolute and relative paths, but nothing has worked. I read something about Firefox not wanting to display local files, but surely that doesn't apply to things running off my computer? I can display lots of local files in my browser normally. Either way, I installed an add-on called LocalLink. This is the code I was trying to use with this method:

```
var img_path;
d3.selectAll( ".node" ).on( "mouseover", function(d) {
  img_path = "{{ image_path }}" + d.name + ".png";
  document.getElementById('thumb').src=img_path;
  document.getElementById('thumb').style.display='block';
```

Here, the python image_path variable is something along the lines of r"file:///C:/Python27/my/app/folders/etc/"

This almost works. The images don't appear on hover, but if I use Firebug and hover over the appropriate  tag in the HTML, the correct image does show up as a thumbnail next to my cursor.

I have tried creating a simple HTML page with an image referring to a "file:///....." location. That works. This makes me think that it is Flask that is the problem with this method. It doesn't seem to have a problem with absolute paths for web locations (I have tested that, and it works), so I am guessing that Flask doesn't like absolute paths to local file locations.

So, there are several possibilities for how this might be solvable:

- There is a way to use url_for with variables generated in the JavaScript.
- There is a way to pass information back to a python variable and use that in url_for.
- There is a way to get Flask to display those images using the "file:///....." format.

Are there other ways?

The only other option I have contemplated is moving the whole thing online. However, I'm not very familiar with Python hosting, and this application uses Twisted and PyQT. I've no idea how I would go about installing them on a server. I don't even know if what I've built would work online - can you use Twisted or PyQT on a live website? I only have a vague sense of what Twisted even does.

If people think this is my best/only option, I will provide a detailed explanation of how my application works, but until that point I won't clutter things up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you are running a Flask application locally (in your browser, you are typing something like `localhost:8000`).

First, you need to understand what `url_for` does. It helps you generate the URL that the static file (in your case, an image or a javascript source file) that the HTML needs to load. So, when you have...

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='d3.js') }}"></script>
```

...the templating engine actually converts this to...

```
<script src="/static/d3.js"></script>
```

If you wanted to, you could have just typed the above into your template (but using url_for is helpful in case you need to change the path to something like /media instead of /static: now you just need to change it in one place rather than change ALL your links).

So, what this means is that when you run Flask, and load the page with the above HTML, the browser knows to find the d3.js script at "localhost:8000/static/d3.js". The browser sends a request to the server (your flask app), and Flask recognizes that it is looking for a static file (because the path starts with `/static`) and returns the d3.js file stored in the `static` directory in your project.

Now, let's say you have a file in your `/static` directory called `static/images/img1.png`. To display this, you would need generate the URL that would pertain to this image (which would be `/static/images/img1.png`). In Flask, you would typically type:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/img01.png') }}"></img>
```

...which would translate to...

```
<img src="/static/img/img01.png"></img>
```

If you wanted to, you could just type this URL. Therefore, your javascript could just generate this URL and it would work.

Now, perhaps you already knew this, but what's bugging you is why you can't, then, do something like `file:///C:/Python27/my/app/folders/etc/`. First, you say that Flask isn't handling this request as you expect. Well, that's because Flask isn't handling this request at all! Remember that Flask is running on something like `localhost:8000`. If you type `<img src="file:///C:/Python27/my/app/folders/etc"></img>`, then the browser is not sending a request to retrieve this file to `localhost:8000`, it's trying to retrieve the file locally using the browser. Likewise, if you have a link on your page for `google.com`, your browser isn't going to send the user that clicked that link to your flask app, they will send them to Google!

For security reasons, if you connect to a web site that is not a local site (e.g., `example.com/index.html` rather than `file:///home/mark/index.html`), Firefox will [not allow you access files directly from the disk](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work). This makes sense, since otherwise going to example.com, the web site could load any file on your hard disk into the web page, which javascript would have access to, then send the information of that file back to the site!

It just so happens that `localhost:8000` is considered a non-local site to browsers. Thus, Firefox will not allow you access to those `file:///...` resources from within that page.

So, this isn't a problem with Flask: this is a problem with using a browser to do things that a browser does not want to do.

Now, what exactly your solution is is going to depend on the needs of your application. The most immediate solution would be to make it so that the images you want to display lie within the `/static` directory of the project.

However, if you want to create a Flask project to do things with files that are placed anywhere on your hard drive (without first having an "upload" page to pick the file from), you might be picking the wrong tool (a web-based application) for the job.

Comment: It works! Thank you for this explanation. I wasn't aware that url_for was just constructing the url like that. However, I was so sure that I had tried all the sensible, plausible url paths for this, but apparently I missed the correct one out.